# Is it safe to call ShowDialog in a method started with Task.Run?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, task

I'm invoking a method that I'd like to have run on a background thread like so:

```
Task.Run(() => CleanupLogs());
```

The `CleanupLogs` method deletes log files older than a certain number of days. It performs the deletion in a try/catch block. If there's an exception, it presents the exception to the user via `Window.ShowDialog`. Is it safe to do that? If not, is there a way to get `Window.ShowDialog` to run on the UI thread?

Comment: What do you mean by safe?

Comment: @EyalPerry I mean will it cause problems like a modal dialog not really being modal or other problems I may not even be aware of. I'm new to WPF but I know that in, for example, iOS all user interaction has to be on the UI thread. I'm trying to find out if there are gotchas with calling ShowDialog from a thread other than the main thread.

Comment: You should rename that method into *CleanupLogsAndShowExceptionIfAny*. If you think this is an ugly name - well, it just describes what you are doing in your code. A *CleanupLogs* method should only cleanup the logs and raise an exception if there is some trouble. Handle that exception (notify user, ...) outside of that method and you never had to think about this kind of questions :o)

Comment: @SSteve In WPF, we do not use such dialogs- we create our own- or grab some framework off of nuget that handles dialogs for us.. Eventually- when you discover MVVM, you will see that using such a dialog is a bad practice. So- don't put too much thought into it.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't get a STA Model exception you should be ok. But if you need to show a window/dialog, make sure you have a reference to the [Dispatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) object which is available on every WPF FrameworkElement (as they inherit from `DispatcherObject`) as well as the main Application class.

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
    DispatcherPriority.Background,
    new Action(() => Window.ShowDialog()));
```

See [WPF Inside Out: Dispatcher](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/arik/2010/08/12/wpf-inside-out-dispatcher/) for more info.